# Error in Solidity Browser compiler

Tags: solidity

I'm using this compiler: https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/

And it's giving me this error:

> Exception during compilation:
>   /src/libevmasm/../libevmasm/Instruction.h(217): Throw in function
>   dev::solidity::Instruction dev::solidity::swapInstruction(unsigned
>   int) Dynamic exception type:
>   N5boost16exception_detail10clone_implIN3dev8solidity13InvalidOpcodeEEE
>   std::exception::what: InvalidOpcode [PN3dev11tag_commentE] = Invalid
>   SWAP instruction requested.

What does that mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: What browser and OS are you using? Do you have any ad-blockers or NoScript? 
Have you tried downloading Browser Solidity locally and running it? Try navigating to https://github.com/ethereum/browser-solidity, select branch gh-pages, download the file that looks like `remix-08d5333.zip`, unzip this on your computer, load index.html in your browser. Do you get the same issue?

Comment: I'm using Chrome on Windows 10. I don't have any ad blockers or NoScript that I know of. I did what you said (downloading remix-08d5333 etc.) and it still showed the same error.

Comment: What is the code that you are attempting to compile?

Comment: I can't post it here. It's proprietary. I can tell you that it is 29540 characters long (822 lines) and doesn't use any fancy code, just basic stuff. There are no external calls and the only internal calls are to private functions. I can give you more information like that if you need it. Let me know.

Comment: Looks like you crashed the compiler- There's probably no good fix on your end. I would remove code in pieces to narrow down the minimal case that causes the error and submit an issue to https://github.com/ethereum/solidity.

Comment: solidity browser isn't useful for the big contracts